# Access value within subclass from superclass

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator, subclass, superclass

I have a superclass called `Main` which maintains a loop.
I made subclasses for it several times in my project, think of `Sub` as one of them.

Each subclass has several methods that are tagged with a decorator (`Main.tag`) and must be called in the subclass loop, I want to save them in `__runs`

```py
class Main:
    __runs = []

    # This method is called in the loop each time, Only for the subclasses, not the main
    def loop(self):
        for run in self.__runs[cls]:
            run(self)
    
    @staticmethod
    def tag(func):
        # Add the func to list
        return func
```

Here is an example of subclasses

```py
class Sub1(Main):
    @Main.tag
    def run_1(self):
        print(1)
        # Doing some tasks
    
    @Main.tag
    def run_2(self):
        print(2)
        # Doing some other stuff

class Sub2(Main):
    @Main.tag
    def run_1(self):
        print(3)
        # Doing some tasks
```

The result should be like this:

```py
>>> s1 = Sub1()
>>> s2 = Sub2()
>>> s1.loop()     # This will be excetued automatically in app
1
2
>>> s2.loop()
3
```

The main goal is to keep subclasses as small as possible
I know I can add sth like `__runs = [run_1, run_2]` but I want to list be flexible with tags and all background staff remains background

Comment: I don't see a dictionary created here anywhere. If you want it to be a list instead of a dictionary, what was stopping you from changing it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 `Main.__runs` is the dictionary I'm talking of. I couldn't change it to a list since this class is inherited in several classes and each class has its own interval time one is running each tick and another one every 5 minutes and the list will run all of them at the same time

Comment: The issue with the dictionary is that since it uses the class name it might get overwrite and I want to prevent it

Comment: @Ashenguard: Could you please edit your question and describe the problem (changing a dict to a list isn't that hard). Btw. did you had a look at classic OOP patterns like [Command](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command/python/example) or [Strategy](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy/python/example) ?

Comment: I can describe my problem like this:
I want to make my decorator (`Main.tag`) add the method/function to a list within the subclass and not be readable in other subclasses. @MauriceMeyer

Comment: I'll try to edit the question and make it more clear

Comment: `Main.__runs` is a class attribute, use `self.__runs` to make it an instance attribute ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Yeah I know but in the decorator, I don't have access to the class since the decorator only argument is the method is defined after (To be exact it's a `<class 'function'>`)